# How do I cash in a Canadian cheque from outside Canada?

Tags: canada, check

I am living outside Canada, and I have cancelled my Canadian phone plan. My phone company has sent me a cheque to refund about C$30 (the prorated unused amount in my phone plan). The cheque is dated May 2019 (about one year old by now). Questions:

1. How can I cash in this cheque from outside Canada?

   - I have a bank account in Canada. Can a friend cash in the cheque for me?
2. Is there an expiry date for the cheque? I do not want to lose the C$30.

Note that it might be many years before I go to Canada again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a bank account in Canada

The top 5 largest banks in Canada all offers a Cheque Deposit through taking photo of the physical cheque via their Mobile App.

https://www.td.com/ca/en/personal-banking/how-to/td-app/deposit-cheque/

https://www.rbcroyalbank.com/ways-to-bank/mobile/rbc-mobile-app/index.html

https://www.scotiabank.com/ca/en/personal/ways-to-bank/mobile-tablet/mobile-deposit.html

https://www.bmo.com/main/personal/ways-to-bank/deposit-money/

https://www.cibc.com/en/personal-banking/ways-to-bank/how-to/use-edeposit.html

As for the second question,

> **Stale-dated**
>
> Cheques are considered stale-dated after six months, unless it is a
>   certified cheque. A stale-dated cheque means that the item is old, and
>   not necessarily invalid. Financial institutions may still honour these
>   items, but there is no obligation to do so. Government of Canada
>   cheques, money orders and bank drafts do not 'stale-date'. Cheques
>   issued by provincial governments are treated as regular cheques and
>   may be considered stale after six months.
>
> -- Payments Canada (formerly the CPA, Canadian Payments Association)

https://www.payments.ca/resources/payment-guides/business-guides/issuing-or-receiving-cheques

Comment: Unfortunately, BMO only allows cheque deposits through its mobile app, but its Android mobile app is region-restricted (i.e. not available for download where I live). I tried to download the iOS app, but the download will not even start (probably region-restricted as well).

Comment: Get a free VPN that lets you tunnel to Canada. Try TunnelBear.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by base64 is excellent and mobile deposit should be used wherever possible. However the questioner indicates that he cannot use the mobile deposit option currently.

You can always deposit a cheque into your account by mailing it to your bank. Simply mail it to your branch (or the bank HQ if you have no branch) with a letter stating "Please deposit the enclosed cheque for $30 into my bank account number 12345678".

Everything base64 says about stale cheques applies to this method also.